# python imaplib login failed socket error: [SSL: BAD_LENGTH] bad length (_ssl.c:2485)

Tags: python, imaplib, python-sockets

I'm developing an application that using imaplib to read all inbox unread emails from mail server `outlook.office365.com`. Sometimes exception `imaplib.IMAP4.abort` occur and when `imaplib.IMAP4.abort` occur I try to shutdown connection to mail server by `logout()` and then instantiate new `imaplib.IMAP4_SSL` and `login()` again, but after login this exception message apear:

> socket error: [SSL: BAD_LENGTH] bad length (_ssl.c:2485)".

What am I doing wrong and how to fix this issue? This is my code:

```
mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(Config.SMTP_SERVER)
mail.login(Config.EMAIL_USER, Config.EMAIL_PASSWORD)
while True:
        try:
            time.sleep(5)
            print('Reading')
            b = time.time()
            mail.select('Inbox')
            mail_type, data = mail.search(None, Config.MAILSTATUS)
            #doing something with mail data herer
            c = time.time() - b
            print('Done in ' + str(c))
        except Exception as e:
            if isinstance(e, imaplib.IMAP4.abort) or isinstance(e, imaplib.IMAP4.error):
                fda_logging.info('email server aborted try to reconnect')
                try:
                    mail.logout()
                    time.sleep(10)
                    mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(Config.SMTP_SERVER)
                    mail.login(Config.EMAIL_USER, Config.EMAIL_PASSWORD)
                    time.sleep(10)
                    fda_logging.info('email server aborted try to reconnect success')
                except Exception as ex:
                    fda_logging.info('email server aborted try to reconnect failed' + str(ex))
```

And this is the traceback:

```
(most recent call last): 
File "main.py", line 53, in read_email_from_inbox mail.select('Inbox') 
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/imaplib.py", line 747, in select typ, dat = self._simple_command(name, mailbox) 
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/imaplib.py", line 1205, in _simple_command return self._command_complete(name, self._command(name, *args))
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/imaplib.py", line 943, in _command raise self.error("command %s illegal in state %s, " imaplib.IMAP4.error: command SELECT illegal in state LOGOUT, only allowed in states AUTH, SELECTED 
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/imaplib.py", line 981, in _command self.send(data + CRLF) File "/usr/lib/python3.8/imaplib.py", line 323, in send self.sock.sendall(data) 
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1204, in sendall v = self.send(byte_view[count:]) File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1173, in send return self._sslobj.write(data) ssl.SSLError: [SSL: BAD_LENGTH] bad length (_ssl.c:2485) 
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "main.py", line 271, in read_email_from_inbox mail.logout() File "/usr/lib/python3.8/imaplib.py", line 633, in logout typ, dat = self._simple_command('LOGOUT') 
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/imaplib.py", line 1205, in _simple_command return self._command_complete(name, self._command(name, *args)) 
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/imaplib.py", line 983, in _command raise self.abort('socket error: %s' % val) imaplib.IMAP4.abort: socket error: [SSL: BAD_LENGTH] bad length (_ssl.c:2485)
```

Comment: Please post the full stack trace.  What line does the exception come from?

Comment: @Max: sorry for late response, I have added the traceback

Comment: @Max: could you please allow me to ask an other question, How can I check current state of the connection, ex: 'LOGOUT', 'AUTH', 'SELECTED' etc...

Comment: Well, you should always check the result of mail.login; if it fails you can't continue.  It looks like what happened is it threw an exception while trying to reconnect, so that your 'mail' object wasn't overwritten in your try, leaving the old object connected.  You then try to login on the dead object you logged out of.  The SSL error usually means there's something wrong with your connection or a firewall on the way.  Basically, your error handling is a bit busted.  You should structure your program such that logging in is part of the main loop, and not part of the recovery in your "Except"

Comment: so you don't end up repeating yourself, and so you don't have two layers of error handling, which leaves you in a bad state.